# Getting error: No default export of 'App.js' to render

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, jsx, expo

I have the following `Snack Expo`:

https://snack.expo.io/r1_WoB744

which is a simplification of the official `react-native-paper` `Snack Expo`:

https://snack.expo.io/@satya164/github.com-callstack-react-native-paper:example

On top of removing all the components except: `{ BottomNavigationExample, CardExample }` I did the following changes:

[image: screenshot]

The I got the above `Snack Expo`, here the link again:

https://snack.expo.io/r1_WoB744

My problem is that when running the app on the online simulator I'm getting the error:

```
Device: (13:5485) No default export of 'App.js' to render!
```

I have to say that 2 or 3 days ago this link worked properly.

Any idea on how to solve this?

If possible, please provide back a working `Snack Expo`.

Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be a babel/tsconfig issue related to RequireJS/ES6 module interoperability. Have you tried using a different version of expo (bottom right pullup menu)? Probably won't make a diff, but looks like tsconfig is controlled through the expo preset.

Comment: yep, I tried previous versions of `Expo` with no success. Any other idea? If possible, could you provide back a working `Snack Expo`?. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

add following to App.js file

```
export default App;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).